# The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\lambda^3(\lambda-1)$. Is $x\mapsto Ax$ surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Suppose the characteristic polynomial of $A\in M_4(\mathbb R)$ is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^3(\lambda-1)$. The mapping
>   $A:\mathbb{R}^4 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^4 $ defined as $A(x)=Ax$ is surjective for some matrices $A$ and for some not. True or false?

My approach:

Since the mapping is from/into the same space, if the operator is surjective then it's also injective ( $\mathbb{dim}N(A)=0$). We know the eigenvalues for this operator: $\lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=\lambda_3=\lambda_4=0$. Since $\mathbb{dim}N(A-\lambda I)\neq0$ (if it was $=0$ then $(A-\lambda I)x=0$ would be true only for $x=0_v$ which is impossible). So we conclude that for the given eigenvalues there isn't such a matrix $A$ that is surjective. So the statement is **FALSE**.

Comment: That's correct. You can make it shorter: the key point is indeed that surjective $\leftrightarrow$ injective. Then you can simply observe that $0$ being an eigenvalue exactly means  the linear map is *not* injective.

Comment: @Bernard thank you for the hint

Comment: Is $p$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$?

Comment: Yes it is. @lhf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Bernard said in comments sums it up, but for the sake of having answer, I'll write it down.

First of all, your argumentation is correct. Just a few observations.

As you said, if you have linear map $A\colon V\to W$ such that $\dim V = \dim W < \infty$, then $A$ is injective iff $A$ is surjective iff $A$ is bijective. This is a simple consequence of rank-nullity theorem.

That said, if $\lambda$ is eigenvalue of $A\in L(V)$, then by definition it means that there exists $v\neq 0$ such that $Av = \lambda v$, i.e. eigenspace $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ of $\lambda$ is non-trivial. It follows that $A-\lambda I$ is not injective, and hence not invertible, or $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$. The converse is true as well, which gives us that eigenvalues are precisely the roots of the characteristic polynomial.

But, the point we need here is that $A$ is not injective if and only if $0$ is eigenvalue of $A$. Since your operator has $0$ as eigenvalue, it is not injective, and hence not surjective.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation